# Installing uwebsockets on pip for mqtt communication

Tags: python

I tried to install uwebsockets on pip but failed. I tried "pip install uwebsockets" for a mqtt project but got error: Could not build wheels for uwebsockets, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the dev made the repo hidden so you can't install it anymore. Maybe you can find a wheel somewhere or use socketify.

source: https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/discussions/1202